# How JSON POST request can be handled by WCF?

Tags: json, wcf, post

I need to handle, in my .net WCF service, JSON data (POST request) from a third party application.
Basically the third party app would be consuming my WCF service.
The posted JSON data structure is known.
I would like to know how the JSON data can be de-serialized in my service?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this? You will usually get better answers if you have a go at the code yourself, post what you have tried along with any errors returned etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create classes and attributes that copy the structure of json data and use this framework for serialization and deserilazation:

[Json Framework](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Classes can be generated here:
[Json to classes](http://json2csharp.com/)